# Finding equilibria and determining their behaviour

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

The simplest model of malaria assumes that the mosquito population is at equilibrium and (only) models the infected humans $I$ with the following equation:

$$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac {}{+}(−)−$$

where  is the natural death rate of mosquitoes, $$ is the death rate of humans, $$ is the transmission rate from infected mosquitoes to susceptible humans, and $$ is the transmission rate from humans to mosquitoes.

Find the equilibria of this model and determine stability conditions for the disease free equilibria to be stable or unstable.

So I know that for this DE to be at equilibrium $\frac {dI}{dt}=0$, and the only way I can come up with for this to be at equilibrium is when $I=0$ ie. the disease free equilibria. I am having difficulty finding any other equilibria. Also, how do I go about determining the stability conditions for the disease free equilibrium ($I=0$, I think) to see whether it is stable or unstable.

Comment: It seems to me that you can find another equilibrium by multiplying both sides of the equilibrium equation by $\alpha I + N r$ and solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: Which corresponds to the state where the number of newly-infected humans is equal to the number of infected humans dying.

Comment: when i solve for the quadratic equation here i get a total mess.. any tips?

Comment: I mean, the actual characterization of that equilibrium will be a pretty nasty mess, given the complexity of your growth term. I don't think that's going anywhere.

Comment: Actually the determination of the nature of each equilibrium is completely standard, as is often the case for 1D models, since only the sign of the RHS matters.

Answer (score 1):

You need
$$
\frac {\alpha\beta I}{\alpha I+Nr}(N-I)-\mu I = 0.
$$
If $I\ne 0$ then you can divide both sides by $I$:
$$
\frac {\alpha\beta}{\alpha I+Nr}(N-I)-\mu = 0.
$$
Can you solve that for $I$?

Comment: yes so that would be the other equilibria then (solved in terms of I)?

Comment: Yes.  But the singular is "equilibrium". $\qquad$